# External Linking and File Creation with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, external

My plan is to link a spreadsheet with data  to a template - every row of data should create a separate file and save it. I have integrated a click button to do that, but it only opens the template and doesn't input data, nor saves it. I think I am missing something.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

' First we define a few variables to capture data from our Excel worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim mydate As String
Dim path As String
Dim myfilename As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Benefits\BasicInvoice.xlsx")

' our last row of data in the worksheet is defined
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' we start at row 2 since the first row contains headers
r = 2

' Looping process starts
For r = 2 To lastrow

' If the value under the header ‘Note’ is done then the data in the row is not processed and jump to the label nextrow

If Cells(r, 17).Value = “done” Then GoTo nextrow

' we map excel worksheet data to the variables

companycode = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 3).Value
profitcentre = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 4).Value
vendorno = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 5).Value
vendorname = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 6).Value
reference = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 7).Value
employeename = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 8).Value
Frequency = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 9).Value
Date = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 10).Value
curr = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 11).Value
amount = Sheets(“GeneralList”).Cells(r, 12).Value


Cells(r, 13).Value = “done”
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Workbooks.Open Filename:="BasicInvoice.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open "BasicInvoice.xlsx"
' Worksheets(“BasicInvoice”).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Activate
' now we map the variables to the invoice worksheet data

wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B8”).Value = vendorno
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B9”).Value = vendorname
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B10”).Value = curr
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B11”).Value = amount
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B12”).Value = Frequency
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B13”).Value = reference
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B14”).Value = employeename
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“A18”).Value = "272240"
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“B18”).Value = profitcentre
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“C18”).Value = companycode
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“D18”).Value = Frequency
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“E18”).Value = Date
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“F18”).Value = amount
wb1.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Cells(“F20”).Value = amount

path = "C:\Benefits\"

mydate = Date
mydate = Format(mydate, “mm_dd_yyyy”)


' File is saved as a read-only file
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & curr & “ - ” & vendorname & “ - ” & mydate & “.xlsx”
myfilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
SetAttr myfilename, vbReadOnly
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut copies:=1

' We close the active workbook. We don’t need to save it because we just saved it!
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

' our label next row. Labels have a colon after their name

nextrow:

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: when you say `lastrow` does that mean `lastrow` of `wb1` or the activesheet

Comment: it doesn't matter because It is the same thing in the beginning before opening the external sheet, right?

Comment: What I meant was, are you trying to count the rows in `wb1` or in `activesheet`??,if it is `activesheet` then  you are good to go,I would recommend you to declare all the workbooks if there are more than 1 for easier understanding of what you are trying to achieve.Present code will not loop thorough `wb1` unless you define what to do `with wb1`

Comment: Move `lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` above `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Benefits\BasicInvoice.xlsx")`

Comment: It has only one workbook. I am using wb1 only to ease declarations such as accessing cells in it's sheets. Itsn't it looping? Sorry I started with VBA 2 hours ago :)

Comment: @Slai Doesn't change anything. Am I not only declaring it with Set. It doesn't mean I made it Active.

Comment: oh never mind .. I think your problem is because you can not have 2 workbooks with the same name "BasicInvoice.xlsx" in the same Excel application. Is that the error you get if you remove `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ?

Comment: It Doesn't give any alerts or errors. I believe it is a logical error when linking, but I have no idea where.